# javascript img DOM not working on github.io but works locally

Tags: javascript

Final edit: ful-stackz solution is correct, I was implementing it incorrectly. I needed to refactor the functions that create divs and css out, then call it from within an anonymous function. Thank you!

I've just started to learn basic html/css/js and I am trying to build a small photoblog. What I've made so far is a site that has a container that holds all the pictures, each picture has a title, source image link, description, and average color of the picture. The title, source image link, description are loaded from a json file in an array format. [ {"src": .., etc }, { } ...]. The site loads all of the menu bar stuff, and when the body finishes loading runs a js that starts to generate dynamically all the divs for the photos(). Code provided below. The function is supposed to parse the json file, and create a new div and set of css rules for each item in the json array. In the process, it also runs ColorThief to get the average color of each picture and passes that onto the css rules, so each div has their own unique background color.

**Here is the problem**: when I run this locally on the machine, everything works perfectly fine. All the pictures are showing up, with the background colors working as expected. But when I run the same thing on github.io (after having pushed and waiting a while for it to update), it does not work. It runs it and when i check the console.log(img.width), shows 0. And ofcourse, the colorthief script fails because you can't have an image size of 0 and expect to get results. *The weird part is that every couple of refreshes, one or two pictures pop up, with what looks like the correct background color (ie.colorthief ran).* When I comment out the colorthief block, the site loads as expected on github.io. That is,all pictures show up and load with the default background color. So i THINK (and I'm a complete noob at this), that something is weird createElement or img.src when the DOM is assigned the attribute.

**What I think isnt the problem**

- I made all the filenames #.jpg, in lowercase, where # is some randomly assigned number starting from 1, numbered sequentially.

  colorthief isn't the problem, i think, as it runs offline fine.. and occasionally online as well(when one or two pictures load, it looks like it has a different background color).

  filenames/paths, as commenting out the colorthief block makes the site load properly.

**thank you for your time and help!!**

This is that "getHighlights()" function, colorthief block highlighted with asterisks. When commented out, site loads fine.:

```
function getHighlights(){
var colorThief = new ColorThief(); // For colorthief to get average color
var img = document.createElement("img");  // For colorthief to get average color
var highlightsJSON = "highlights.json";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    // var html = "";
    var currentElement = "";
    var myArrLength = myArr.length;

    // loads the current stylesheet as a variable
    var myStyle = document.styleSheets[0]; 




    // HTML Template to create each highlight box

    // <div id="highlightXXX">
    // <a href="#"><img src="XXX" alt="XXX" ></a>
    // <div id="highlightXXX-title">XXX</div>
    // <div id="highlight1-descXXX">XXX</div>
    // </div>



    for(var i = 0; i< myArrLength; i++){
        var html = "";
        var idNumber = i+1;
        var src = myArr[i].src;
        var title = myArr[i].title;
        var desc = myArr[i].desc;
        var href = myArr[i].href;
        var bgRedChannel = 255;
        var bgGreenChannel = 255;
        var bgBlueChannel = 255;

        //****************************************************
        // for ColorThief - remove code block to disable
        img.src = src;
        console.log(img.width); // **this yields width of 0**
        bgColor = colorThief.getColor(img);
        bgRedChannel = bgColor[0];
        bgGreenChannel = bgColor[1];
        bgBlueChannel = bgColor[2];



        // creates the CSS rules for each highlight
        createHighlightCSS(myStyle, idNumber, bgRedChannel, bgGreenChannel, bgBlueChannel);

        // creates the unique containers for each highlight
        html += `<div id="highlight${idNumber}">`;
        html += `<a href="${href}"><img src="${src}" alt="${title}" ></a>`;
        html += `<div id="highlight${idNumber}-title">${title}</div>`;
        html += `<div id="highlight${idNumber}-desc">${desc}</div>`;
        html += `</div>\n`
        document.getElementById("highlights-container").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    }

}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", highlightsJSON, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

2018-05-22 update:
So I added the listener, and it didn't seem to help :(.

```
    function getHighlights(){
console.log("build 2018-05-22 7:13pm")
var colorThief = new ColorThief(); // For colorthief to get average color
var img = document.createElement("img");  // For colorthief to get average color
var highlightsJSON = "highlights.json";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    // var html = "";
    var currentElement = "";
    var myArrLength = myArr.length;

    // loads the current stylesheet as a variable
    var myStyle = document.styleSheets[0]; 




    // HTML Template to create each highlight box

    // <div id="highlightXXX">
    // <a href="#"><img src="XXX" alt="XXX" ></a>
    // <div id="highlightXXX-title">XXX</div>
    // <div id="highlight1-descXXX">XXX</div>
    // </div>



    for(var i = 0; i< myArrLength; i++){

        var idNumber = i+1;
        var src = myArr[i].src;
        var title = myArr[i].title;
        var desc = myArr[i].desc;
        var href = myArr[i].href;
        var bgRedChannel = 255;
        var bgGreenChannel = 255;
        var bgBlueChannel = 255;
        var bgColor;


        // for ColorThief - remove code block to disable
        // creates the unique containers for each highlight
        img.src = src;


        img.addEventListener("load", console.log(img.width));  // instead of console.log I placed bgColor= colorThief.getColor(img) here, and it didn't help. I put the console.log here to debug to see whether it would give a valid width, and unfortunately it didn't :(.

        bgColor = colorThief.getColor(img)
        bgRedChannel = bgColor[0];
        bgGreenChannel = bgColor[1];
        bgBlueChannel = bgColor[2];

        // creates divs only after loaded
        createHighlightHTML(idNumber, href, title, desc, src)


        // creates the CSS rules for each highlight
        createHighlightCSS(myStyle, idNumber, bgRedChannel, bgGreenChannel, bgBlueChannel);


    }

}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", highlightsJSON, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Edit 2018-05-23 11:49pm ; still doesn't work :(

```
    function getHighlights(){
console.log("build 2018-05-23 11:44pm")

var img = document.createElement("img");  // For colorthief to get average color
var highlightsJSON = "highlights.json";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    // var html = "";
    var currentElement = "";
    var myArrLength = myArr.length;

    // loads the current stylesheet as a variable
    var myStyle = document.styleSheets[0]; 


    // HTML Template to create each highlight box

    // <div id="highlightXXX">
    // <a href="#"><img src="XXX" alt="XXX" ></a>
    // <div id="highlightXXX-title">XXX</div>
    // <div id="highlight1-descXXX">XXX</div>
    // </div>



    for(var i = 0; i< myArrLength; i++){

        var idNumber = i+1;
        var src = myArr[i].src;
        var title = myArr[i].title;
        var desc = myArr[i].desc;
        var href = myArr[i].href;
        var bgRedChannel = 255;
        var bgGreenChannel = 255;
        var bgBlueChannel = 255;



        // for ColorThief - remove code block to disable
        // creates the unique containers for each highlight
        img.src = src;


        img.addEventListener("load", createHighlightCSS(myStyle, idNumber, bgRedChannel, bgGreenChannel, bgBlueChannel, img));

        // creates divs only after loaded
        createHighlightHTML(idNumber, href, title, desc, src);



        // creates the CSS rules for each highlight




    }

}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", highlightsJSON, true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}

    function createHighlightCSS(myStyle, idNumber, bgRedChannel, bgGreenChannel, bgBlueChannel, img){
var widthAndHeight = "300px";
var titleFontSize = "1.6em";
var colorThief = new ColorThief(); // For colorthief to get average color
bgColor = colorThief.getColor(img)
bgRedChannel = bgColor[0];
bgGreenChannel = bgColor[1];
bgBlueChannel = bgColor[2];
console.log(bgColor);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two questions to clarify, but since I can't write comments here comes an answer.

1. Are you sure that the path to your `highlights.json` is correct? (Though, I guess it is)
2. When you make an `img` element and set it's `src` to something, that something needs to be loaded first. Perhaps, your image doesn't load immediately and that is why you are getting `img.width = 0` and from there everything fails as you say. `img` elements fire a `load` event when the image is done loading - `img.addEventListener('load', func...`.

## Update to answer comment question

One way to do it would be to wait for the desired image to be loaded and then do your thing. I will give an example with an anonymous function, though it will definitely not be pretty, but you'll get the idea.

```
...
var bgBlueChannel = 255;


//****************************************************
// for ColorThief - remove code block to disable
img.src = src;
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // this = the img element
  console.log(this.width); // will now give the correct width
  bgColor = colorThief.getColor(this);
  bgRedChannel = bgColor[0];
  bgGreenChannel = bgColor[1];
  bgBlueChannel = bgColor[2];

  // creates the CSS rules for each highlight
  createHighlightCSS(myStyle, idNumber, bgRedChannel, bgGreenChannel, bgBlueChannel);

  // creates the unique containers for each highlight
  html += `<div id="highlight${idNumber}">`;
  html += `<a href="${href}"><img src="${this.src}" alt="${title}" ></a>`;
  html += `<div id="highlight${idNumber}-title">${title}</div>`;
  html += `<div id="highlight${idNumber}-desc">${desc}</div>`;
  html += `</div>\n`
  document.getElementById("highlights-container").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
});

...
```

Comment: Hello ful-stackz, thank you for your response!
1) yes th ehighlights.json is right.
2) that sounds like it could be it, since sometimes it loads and sometimes it doesnt. Would the following be a correct implementation? I am not sure how to check that the img has loaded or what that entails when it hasn't been set.


`img.addEventListener("load", img.src = src);
   console.log(img.width);
   bgColor = colorThief.getColor(img);
   bgRedChannel = bgColor[0];
   bgGreenChannel = bgColor[1];
   bgBlueChannel = bgColor[2];`

Comment: or do you add the listener first?

`// for ColorThief - remove code block to disable
   
   img.addEventListener("load", console.log(img.width));
   img.src = src;
   
   bgColor = colorThief.getColor(img);
   bgRedChannel = bgColor[0];
   bgGreenChannel = bgColor[1];
   bgBlueChannel = bgColor[2];`

Comment: Updated the answer with an example, because it is more readable than a comment. Hope that fixes it, because I don't have other ideas about the problem.

Comment: Hey, man! You got me curious about your problem. Did you work it out?

Comment: i haven't tried the fix yet but i'll definitely report back by the weekend. (lots of deadline this week) Thanks for checking in!!

Comment: Hey, @ful-stackz , I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work :( . I ran it also with a removelistener thing at the end of the loop and it didn't matter either way. Was really hoping that it would work, any other ideas? Thanks man!

Comment: Hello! If what you did is `img.addEventListener("load", console.log(img.width));` or `img.addEventListener("load", bgColor= colorThief.getColor(img));` it will not work at all. See, when you are adding an event listener, in the second parameter you must pass an anonymous function or a reference to an already defined function. I can't explain it well here in plain text, so if you want give me some messenger details of yours (discord is fine). Otherwise, copy-paste the code in my answer, it's different than what you are doing and I think it'll work.

Comment: ok! I will give it a try in a couple hours and then dm you. Thank you for the explanation!!

Comment: apparently stack doesn't have DM, my discord is a12b4c3 though, thanks!!! But I just tried it and it doesn't work still unfortunately... really thought that was going to do it also =/ 

the files are at https://a12b4c3.github.io/p1-photoblog/

Comment: I checked the source and see where the problem might be. Discord asks for a `We need a12b4c3's four digit tag so we know which one they are` My discord is `herros#1258`